# Discord.js XMLHTTPRequest Returns Blank Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, discord.js

I'm working in DiscordAPI using Discord.js, but I've run into an issue. When using XMLHttpRequest, I get an error in the console saying:

`(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

This is the block of code that handles everything:

```
const imgcommand = ["!g img"];
const imgcommandcut = message.content;
const imgsearchparam = imgcommandcut.replace(/!g img /, "");
const imgsearchcut = imgsearchparam.replace(/ /g, "%20")
var imgparams = imgsearchcut;
if( imgcommand.some(word => message.content.includes(word)) ) {
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyBZEJ2dYHtnsn4DJLq6QzXJo4umiHlam5M&cx=017268685753925817424:6rgr_rfrawg&q=" + "?" + imgparams + "&searchType=image&fileType=jpg&imgSize=xlarge&alt=json", false);
xhr.send();
message.channel.send(xhr.response);
}
```

I've pasted the link into Chrome and got a JSON text block, so the link works. Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit V3: I've updated the code per @Blundering's suggestions and this is what I have

```
const imgcommand = ["!g img"];
const imgcommandcut = message.content;
const imgsearchparam = imgcommandcut.replace(/!g img /, "");
const imgsearchcut = imgsearchparam.replace(/ /g, "%20")
var imgparams = imgsearchcut;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {

      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log("XHR GET SUCCESSFUL")
      } else {
          console.log("XHR NOT SUCCESSFUL " + xhr.readyState + "and " + xhr.status)
      }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyBZEJ2dYHtnsn4DJLq6QzXJo4umiHlam5M&cx=017268685753925817424:6rgr_rfrawg&q=dog&searchType=image&fileType=jpg&imgSize=xlarge&alt=json', true);

    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
        if( imgcommand.some(word => message.content.includes(word)) ) {
            console.log(xhr.reponse)
            let msg = xhr.response;
            if (!msg) msg == '';

            message.channel.send(msg)
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    });
    xhr.send();
```

Answer (score -1):

**First:** To solve the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error:

The discord function `message.channel.send("<message>")` returns a promise, so the error you're getting is telling you that `xhr.response` (which you're sending to the server) is empty.

To properly handle this error (as Discord requests), add a `.catch` call after the `.send` function like this:

```
message.channel.send(xhr.response)
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**Second:** To solve the `DiscordAPIError`:

```
{ DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at item.request.gen.end (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:68:65)
    at then (/app/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:218:21)
    at <anonymous> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  name: 'DiscordAPIError',
  message: 'Cannot send an empty message',
  code: 50006 }
```

This is caused by an empty value being sent in your `message.channel.send(...)` function. The value you have to put in that `send` function has to be resolvable to a string (as seen in the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)), meaning the `.send` function has to be able to figure out what kind of string to make. Your issue is that `xhr.response` is empty, and `.send` doesn't know how to make a string from it. To avoid the error, you should make sure that variable is populated before you send it in a message. Like this:

```
let msg = xhr.response;

// if there's nothing stored in xhr.response, set msg to empty string
if (!msg) msg = '';

// then you can send msg without worrying about errors
message.channel.send( msg );
```

**Third:** To solve your issue where `xhr.response` is `undefined`:

Now that you're doing an asynchronous `xhr.open` call, you can not just get `xhr.response` a few lines after you send the request. Instead, you have to set up a listener, so when the data comes back you can deal with it (either in `xhr.response` or `xhr.responseText`).

Here is an example adapted from the [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) method from the docs:

```
xhr.open("GET", '<your url>', true);
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if( imgcommand.some(word => message.content.includes(word)) ) {
        let msg = xhr.response;
        if (!msg) msg == '';

        message.channel.send(msg)
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Returns this error:
{ DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
at item.request.gen.end (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:68:65)
at then (/app/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:218:21)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
name: 'DiscordAPIError',
message: 'Cannot send an empty message',
code: 50006 }

Comment: Hey @CloudyDays - I added more to my answer, including a question asking why you're setting the third parameter of `xhr.open` to `false`, which means you're doing a synchronous get request instead of asynchronous

Comment: I have done all of that and added a line of code that logs the readyState of the request and it comes up in the console as undefined. I've learned that the readyState should never be undefined. What could be causing this? I've also changed the GET to asynchronous.

Comment: @CloudyDays - that shouldn't be possible. Please add your new code to the bottom of your question so I can try to help troubleshoot

Comment: I've updated the question, let me know what you think.

Comment: @CloudyDays - Thanks for updating - looks like you're using `this.readyState`, but you should use `xhr.readyState` - I put this in my answer

Comment: Getting somewhere! I've updated the code above, and the readyState now returns complete. The problem of having xhr.open() return an undefined response still stands.

Comment: @CloudyDays - updated - has to be in a function listening for the response, since it's an asynchronous request

Comment: Updated. Still getting an undefined. Is there a limit to how many characters the responseText can be? The responseText from my URL is around 10,000 characters.

Comment: You're getting a value from `xhr.responseText` but not from `xhr.response`??

Comment: When I enter the URL into an actual browser like Chrome, the JSON that it returns is around 10,000 characters. In the script, I don't get a response from either.

Comment: 1) I Copy / pasted your code, changed the `addEventListener` callback function to: `function() { console.log(xhr.response.length) }` and I got 11541, which means it is returning all of the json. 2) you can get ride of your `xhr.onload` function since that and `addEventListener` do the same thing.

Comment: Try adding that `console.log(xhr.response) in the `addEventListener`'s callback function

Comment: I've removed my `xhr.onload` function, but I'm a tad confused on what exactly you did with the `addEventListener`. Please explain.